# cmake: linking software to boost::mpi (with mpich2)

Tags: cmake, mpi, boost-mpi

For this simple code (taken from the boost-mpi documentation):

```
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
    mpi::communicator world;

    if (world.rank() == 0) {
      world.send(1, 0, std::string("Hello"));
      std::string msg;
      world.recv(1, 1, msg);
      std::cout << msg << "!" << std::endl;
    } else if (world.rank() == 1) {
      std::string msg;
      world.recv(0, 0, msg);
      std::cout << msg << ", ";
      std::cout.flush();
      world.send(0, 1, std::string("world"));
    };

  return 0;
};
```

And for such CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(mpi-tests CXX)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.4 COMPONENTS mpi serialization REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

It cannot find boost_mpi:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1135 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
  Boost version: 1.47.0
  Boost include path: /usr/include
  The following Boost libraries could not be found:
          boost_mpi
```

But! I have installed next packages:

```
boost-graph-mpich2
boost-mpich2
boost-mpich2-devel
boost-mpich2-python
mpich2
mpich2-devel
```

Why it can't find? There are a plenty examples over Internet where people use **FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.4 COMPONENTS mpi REQUIRED)**.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Uhm. That 1.4 in find_package() seems strange. Did you tried 1.47.0?

Comment: That's just the minimum version of Boost that can be used. It find `Boost version: 1.47.0`. Changing into 1.47.0 didn't work.

I have found, that boost-mpich2 installs libraries into `/usr/lib/mpich2/` (or, `/usr/lib64/mpich2/` for x86_64 architecture). And, moreover, boost libraries are in `/usr/{lib,lib64}/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost might not be installed in a location that the module FindBoost searches.  You can specify the prefix where Boost was installed by setting the variable BOOST_ROOT to your Boost installation prefix.

To your code I would add:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(mpi-tests CXX)
set( BOOST_ROOT "/path/to/boost/install/prefix" )
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.4 COMPONENTS mpi serialization REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```